# Combo Box not populating correctly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, business-objects

I am populating a combobox from a list of business objects using the following code:

```
Dim manufacturers As IList(Of ElectronicsManufacturer) = _electronicLogic.GetManufacturers(category.CategoryID)

            If (manufacturers.Count > 0) Then

                Me.cbxManufacturer.Enabled = True
                Me.cbxManufacturer.Items.Add("(Please Select...)")
                Me.cbxManufacturer.Items.Add(manufacturers.ToArray())
```

The issue I have is that the Combobox is not displaying the Strings but instead the business object name.

I have an override set up in the Business Object as I normally do:

```
    public class ElectronicsManufacturer
{
    public ElectronicsManufacturer()
    {
        ManufacturerID = -1;
        ManufacturerName = string.Empty;
        RequireSerialNumber = false;
    }

    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
    public bool RequireSerialNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ManufacturerName.ToString();
    }


}
```

But the combobox just displays ElectronicsManufacturer[] Array

I can confirm that `manufacturers` at point of populating the combobox contains 52 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH!

That's embarrassing.

Straight after posting I noticed I was adding an array using the Add rather than AddRange command.

Sorry to of wasted your time!